# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Calle'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object with autoincrement option activated

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm migrating an old database which has no Identity constraints and I'm adding to the new one and everything worked fine, but when I checked the logs files I've created, I notice this error, the weird part of it is the table have Identity key with autoincrement of 1

The code I'm using is this:

```
var cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
cmd1.Connection = mySqlConnection;
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd1.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [Tomin].[TominPredial].[Calle]([Nombre],[Id_Colonia]"
                    + ",[Id_User],[Id_Date])"
                    + " VALUES(@Nombre,@Id_Colonia,@Id_User,@Id_Date)";
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", nombreCalle);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Colonia", id_col);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_User", "Admin");
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Date", DateTime.Now);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I don't know what is this happening since I don't send the primary key because I suppose the autoincrement will set it for me, any idea what's going on?

The value that is the ID that throws the error begins in 1 and ends in 562, when I delete data, after doing it i use `DBCC CHECKIDENT('Tomin.TominPredial.Calle', RESEED, 0)`

```
CREATE TABLE TominPredial.Calle (
Id_Calle SMALLINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_Calle PRIMARY KEY,
Nombre NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Id_Colonia SMALLINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_Calle_Colonia REFERENCES TominPredial.Colonia (Id_Colonia),
Id_User NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_Calle_User REFERENCES TominUsuario.Usuario (ID),
Id_Date DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
Id_Estatus TINYINT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_Calle_Estatus REFERENCES TominSistema.Estatus (Id_Estatus)
);
GO
```

Comment: Any triggers that update other tables?

Comment: @Steve no, and also I check for the key it's supposed to set and ideed it's already taken

Comment: What is the ID value or values that it errors on..? have you thought about re-seeding the DB then trying to Inserts..? can you provide a few examples of what the values are that you are inserting.. have you checked to see if there are other constraints on the new DB..also show what the Table Schema / Definition looks like please

Comment: Wrap all that code around a Try {} Catch as well so you can hopefully capture the true exception, also make sure you are not passing in a value for the Auto Increment field, clear the log and add some better logging as well hope this info helps

Comment: Can you change the small int for Id_Calle field to a Integer? why are you declaring it as smallint change it to Int or BigInt look at this reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx you also have foreign key constraints ..

Comment: @DJKRAZE the foraign key constraints are sended well, I'll try changing smallint, but the last id is around 5k

Comment: what do you mean by sended..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE that the values sended in the insert statement are right, I mean the conflict is where I said

Comment: can you remove the constraints then add them back later..after all the data has been imported in.. my only concern with that is that you may have duplicates.. is this one to many ...? please add as much detail as you can..

Comment: @DJKRAZE weird thing, I delete the DB and re-create and the error doesn't throws again, what could be the problem??

Comment: I am thinking it's the creating of the restraints and or something got corrupt.. good thing is that it's working

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thanks buddie, just one more thing, if I want to delete de data in order to avoid delete it and then re-create, what can I do to avoid those errors?

Comment: You need to run / execute a SQL Delete statement for example 
DELETE FROM TableName
Commit;

Comment: @DJKRAZE I did it that way and I think it's the problem, well anyway thanks a lot

Comment: Use TRUNCATE TABLE, this will reset the identity seed